# ember-emojione: serving individual PNG images from a custom CDN?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, emojione, ember-emojione

I'm using [ember-emojione](https://github.com/Deveo/ember-emojione).

I would like to display emoji as individual PNGs. I want those PNGs served from a custom domain.

How can I configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

1. In your app's `ember-cli-build.js`, set sprites and asset inclusion to disabled:

   ```
   'ember-emojione': {
     spriteSheet:            false,
     shouldIncludePngSprite: false,
   },
   ```

   Other types of images are not included by default.
2. In your app's `config/environment.js`, define the path to PNG emoji on your CDN:

   ```
   "ember-emojione": {
     emojione: {
       imageType:    'png',
       imagePathPNG: 'https://my.cdn.com/emojione/png/',
     }
   }
   ```